# Getting a macro to run using checkbox in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to google sheets so I apologise in advance if this seems too basic.
My macro seemed to work fine on computers, I assigned it to a 'shape' button but since it needs to also be functional on a ipad, I searched about it and the answer found was to use an onEdit(e) trigger and use checkbox to set it up.
My issue now is that there's no assign button to have the macro attributed to the checkbox when it's checked :')

I have no issue sharing the script if needed because it's a very simple one.

Comment: `onEdit` captures any manual edits you do on the sheet and the `onEdit` function is triggered. You do not need any button to execute the macro if you decide to use `onEdit`. Can you show what your macro tries to do?

Comment: I guess the manual edit would be checking the checkbox. 
What the macro does is duplicate the sheet in a new one then past_values so the formulas won't be there anymore and delete the previous sheets with the data that was used to fill that final one. I'll paste it here in a sec @NaziA

Comment: Can you show the macro instead? I might miss something.

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/VLoXo1Eo @NaziA this is the macro so far

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Kindly check

Comment: Was the answer able to fix your issue? @AnnaO.?

Comment: sorry for the delay @NaziA  I was only able to get back to it today! It worked fine just now ! Thank you a lot!

Comment: No problem @Anna. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the code works, CarlosM's provided answer is already almost correct.

I'll just have to combine it together with your macro

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Update if your checkBox is located somewhere else
  var checkBoxLocation = "A1";
  // Change to false if you want to run the macro when checkBox is unticked
  var checkBoxCondition = true;
  // Since getA1Notation and getValue are both methods
  // We need to add () for them to work
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == checkBoxLocation) {
    if (e.range.getValue() == checkBoxCondition) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
      spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('Estimate ');
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(0);

      var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
      sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

      spreadsheet.getRange('E7').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Clients List'), true);
      spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
      spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
      spreadsheet.getRange('A39:H39').activate();
    }
  }
}
```

The code above does execute your macro if the conditions are met. These conditions are:

- The checkBox location is found in variable `checkBoxLocation`
- The checkBox was ticked, this will execute your macro

To quickly check the behavior of the logic of your script, kindly try this one. Make sure to have a checkBox in `A1` before trying the code.

#### Test Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var checkBoxLocation = "A1";
  var checkBoxCondition = true;
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == checkBoxLocation) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('D2');
    if (e.range.getValue() == checkBoxCondition) {
      cell.setValue("A1 checkbox is ticked");
    }
    else {
      cell.setValue("A1 checkbox is unticked");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A checkbox is just a True or False value in a cell, checking/unchecking it triggers the `onEdit(e)` function. You just need to check the location of the checkbox and it's value to execute the macro.

Sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation == "A1") {
    if (e.range.getValue == true) {
      // execute something
    } 
    else {
      // execute something else
    }
  }
}
```